# Httpd error and access logs not updating

Tags: logging, httpd

My httpd error and access logs are not updating. They have a few entries each but when I try to visit my site or when I encounter a cgi 500 error, nothing is recorded. How can I fix this?

Comment: Change the configuration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you logs enabled ? Check that the [ErrorLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog) and [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directives in your apache configuration files are valid and not commented out with a `#` in front of them.

Comment: They are valid. I can see some entries in the log. It's just that new ones aren't added